# Keyframe the ocean modifier time property

Tags: python, animation

I'm using blender 2.8 and i'm just now starting to code in blender and i'm trying to set a keyframe to the Time value in ocean modifier using python

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='OCEAN')
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `keyframe_insert`**

Two things here,

- Add modifiers with `Object.modifiers.new(...)` returns a reference to
  the modifier
- Add keyframes with `keyframe_insert(datapath)` method.  Set the value, insert the keyframe.

Test script

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=2, location=(0, 0, 0))
ob = context.object
om = ob.modifiers.new(name="Ocean", type='OCEAN')
# (frame, time) pairs
data = ((1, 1.0),
        (10, 3.0),
        (100, 33.0),
        )
for f, t in data:
    om.time = t
    om.keyframe_insert("time", frame=f)
```

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly