# How do I write a function that changes current frame to 150 if current frame is 250

Tags: python

I've a script that starts render animation from frame 1 to 250, I want a script that changes the current frame to 150 when it reaches 250

I'm trying to write a function that changes current frame to 150 if current frame is 250

here's my code:

```
def stop_playback(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == 250:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_playback)

bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()


    def change_frame():
        if scene.frame_current == 250:
            bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_set(150)

        change_frame()
```

here's my console output:

```
>>> def change_frame():
...     if scene.frame_current == 250:
...         bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_set(150)
...         
>>> change_frame()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<blender_console>", line 2, in change_frame
NameError: name 'scene' is not defined
```

Comment: Should be a Python only question. Python need indentations (tabs) inside a block. def is a block (add a tab under it) If is a block (add a second tab level under it). But see Python docs, it's better.

Comment: @lemon upd: edited

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145980/link-python-array-to-x-position-of-element/145982#145982. Your last edit: 'change_frame' is called inside 'change_frame' and with no parameters (it is called inside due to the indentation).

Comment: Also have a look here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143273/how-to-create-a-tetrix-sierpinski-tetrahedron-fractal-radiating-from-0-0-0-pyt/144493#144493 at the "Scene handler" part. The idea it is done is if you dont remove before adding you will append several times the same handler.

Comment: There shouldn't be any indentations in front your `def change_frame():`. And also, `scene` is not a references at that function. The `scene` in other function block should not be called here. You might want to pass that value as a parameter inside the parentheses `def change_frame(scene_at_this_function):`.

Comment: And the most important thing, you **shouldn't call a function inside that function unless it will eventually stop in some condition**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Scene.frame_set(...)`**

All [handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.app.handlers.html) take a single argument, `scene`. In some [handlers](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.app.handlers.html), load for example, the `scene` argument has value `None` in which case is often referred to as "`dummy`"

```
import bpy

def skip_playback(scene):
    if scene.frame_current >= 250:
        scene.frame_set(150)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(skip_playback)
```

The `scene` in the handler is the scene being "handled"..  Using a data reference like `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]` is a slippery slope, when there is no scene named  "Scene" or there is another scene's handler will set its frame.

Similar functionality could be achieved by setting the scene frame start and end, or preview start and end.

On your error, it is a basic syntax error in that you have not defined scene in the `change_frame` method.

I would recommend, when you are new (or not) to python,  when you get an error you don't understand make a search for "Python `NameError`"  (*based on the error type `NameError` in this case*)